# Run PHP file to get value for field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know I can include a PHP file with an echo to use as a value in form:

```
value="<? include('generatecode.php'); ?>">
```

But is it possible to send a value to this php file before it generates the code? For example in this PHP file it has an if statement relating to a value...

```
if ($value == 1) { do this } else { do this }
```

Is there any way I can use a checkbox that sends $value to this php file and updates if the box is checked or unchecked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you understand the code you are including? sounds like you don't know how php includes work...

Comment: Once you include the php file, I expect that a variable that was set at the level that called it should be available to the code you included - as long as it has the same name.

Comment: what could be possible values?

Comment: @Jakub, I understand what I've done there, because it's working... Lets just say that if value == 1 it echos "value1" else it echos "value2" at the moment, it's just echoing "value2" because there is no value, therefor it can't == 1.

What I'm saying is I wondered if there was a way around sending the value from a checkbox and then running "generatecode.php". I know this wouldn't be using it as an include, but I don't know how to go about sending the value and calling "generatecode.php" upon giving the checkbox a value.

Comment: I still think you don't know how includes work, it is effectively making 1 big file. PHP is parsed top to bottom, so you cannot set a variable `==1` and expect the included file to handle that if that value is cleared/set in that file. You will have to rewrite something or make some changes to your include functions. I would make the include file just function or a re-usable object. It is hard to tell tho without seeing the code/function.

Comment: I know how includes work, that's why I was saying I need an alternative to an include. It's sorted now anyway, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Ajax to do this:

Lets suppose u have a checkbox with an id of `#check` then :

```
$('#check').click(function() {
  var checkVal;      

  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    checkVal = 'checked';
  } else {
    checkVal = 'unchecked';
  }

  $.post('generatecode.php', {input : chechVal}, function(data) {
    // do something with the data returned from generatecode.php
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

In the generatecode.php file:

```
//catch the checkVal variabe u sent
$checkVal = $_POST['input'];

//do somthing with it, depending what you do the output will be in the *data* variable in the above js script
if($checkVal == something) {
   //do something
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

**NOTE :**
What the above code does is from the page you are at the moment catches if the checkbox with id `#check` is checked or not.Then sends to generatecode.php the relative **checked** or **unchecked** ,there this gets caught in a PHP variable and depending on its value performs an operation which result then gets back to your starting page as a jquery variable `data`, which then you can manipuate as you like instead of alerting it as i did above.

Hope this helped feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, exactly what I needed to do thank you.

With the returning value i've done this:

  `$.post('generatecode.php', {input : chechVal}, function(data) {
    // do something with the data returned from generatecode.php
    $('#textarea').val(data);
  });`

And that works perfectly for what I need it to using jquery to assign the data to the textarea. Is this good practice the way i've implemented it?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It is fine yeah:) Additionally in case you weren't familiar with Ajax i explained in brief what it does. Glad i was able to help:)

Comment: I've very rarely use Ajax, the only other time I've used it is to check if a username is available or take, much the same way, but I didn't understand it enough to write the code from scratch. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to your variable in your main file.  As soon as you include the file, `$value` will be available in your included file.

```
<?php
  $value = 1;
?>
  value="<?php include('generatecode.php'); ?>">
```

This is kind of a weird way of assigning a value to what I assume is an HTML input element.  Typically, you would generate some value and assign it to a variable in your include file and then output the variable.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I want value to be decided by a checkbox and if the checkbox is changed, to update the file. Kind of how you can check if a username exists in a database as you type the username.

Comment: *sidenote:* You mixed PHP short tags and long tags in same piece of codes, which is not advised. Also, normally PHP start tags are in lowercase.